# SQL Server works in CLI but not PDO

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm running this; the SQL that's outputted in the die() works fine when copied and pasted into the console, but it's throwing an error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

when I'm running it through PDO.

I'm connecting to a SQL Azure table.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
try {
   $conn = new PDO ("sqlsrv:server = tcp:nczf1z2h11.database.windows.net,1433; Database = StonewashActions", "core", "ExphaickyaleisUdjak-");
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} 
catch (PDOException $e) {
   //nada
}

try {

   $data = $conn->exec($finalStatement);

} 
catch (Exception $e) {
  die($finalStatement);
}
```

Comment: `GO` is **not** a T-SQL keyword - it's a **delimiter** that's only valid and present inside SQL Server Management Studio. You cannot use it in your T-SQL srcipts

Comment: Right! Any smart ideas on how I can achieve the same thing? The inserts I'm running are taking 20+ seconds, whereas this command, in the console runs in less than 1sec

Comment: Typically, you'd have to split up your SQL commands into multiple scripts and run each separately, so that it is its own "batch" - same thing can be done from an application - just "break" your large script at each `GO` and execute each part of the script separately (send it to SQL Server and have it executed, then take the next part and execute that, and so on until you're done)

Comment: don't understand - achieve the same thing as what? `GO`? Just delete the GO and finish the statement with a `;`

Comment: @whytheq: doesn't always work! Things like `CREATE PROCEDURE` **must** be the first statement in a batch - that **won't work** if you just delete out all `GO` occurrences .... The approach with having individual files (or just individual "executions" of batches) works **always**.